# http to https redirect without www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The same question was asked someone else on stackoverflow but when I tried the solution provided in it, it didn't solve my purpose. My current .htaccess code looks like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I've a domain xyz which has been recently upgraded with SSL. The older version of the domain URL was http://www.xyz.in while after update the new url has become https://xyz.in. What I'm trying to do is redirecting the complete site URLs to the https version that does not have www included in the new structure now. I tried the above given code but it is not solving my purpose. It is only redirecting the homepage to new URL but other old urls are not redirecting to the new secure path. Can anyone please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

I finally fixed this myself. I had to create .htaccess files for each individual directory and adding the above code as given in the question posted above. It solved my issue.